# JavaFX-8: Custom Layout and Layout Passes (layout pass/css pass): Where should I add child nodes?

Tags: layout, javafx, custom-controls

I'm developing a custom table component for very large and very custom content. Therefore I decided not to go with `TableView`, but start from scratch (i.e. `Control`). I adopted the idea of the `VirtualFlow` to create and manage only the visible part of the table and reuse cells that have become invisible. However I needed virtual rows and columns.

My CustomVirtualFlow implements `layoutChildren()`. From the component's size and scrollbar positions I know which cells are visible. If necessary, I add cells to the VirtualFlow. I then update the content and css pseudo class states (selected, focused, ...).

This works almost fine ... currently, my only problem is that the css styles are sometimes lagging: newly created cells are shown with e.g. wrong backgrounds for a moment and then get correcteted with the next pulse.

My explanation for this is that JavaFX performs layout in two passes: 
first a css pass and secondly the layout pass that calls layoutChildren().
The css of newly added children (during layoutChildren) is therefore not processes correctly.

I tried to call applyCss() directly, which helps, but seems to do too much because it takes a lot of time.

My question is: 
How is the correct way to add nodes during layout, i.e. if the size of the component makes it neccessary to use further nodes?
If it is not during layoutChildren(), where else should I do it?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, your assumptions about css pass and layout pass are correct. In [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless), which tries to provide a better VirtualFlow (but is virtualized only in one direction), I also call `applyCss()` explicitly right after adding new cells. It seems to work reasonably well. But yes, this has been a major pain. Make sure to invoke `applyCss()` only on the newly added cells, not the whole VirtualFlow.

Comment: @TomasMikula Thanks for your hints -- invoking applyCss() only on the newly created cells saves some time and "works reasonably well", as you said. :) Still not sure, what would the the right moment/place to add cells.

Comment: This is the best resource I was able to get on this topic: https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/dynamical_layouts_in_fx So you can add child nodes either in `layoutChildren` or `compute*` methods, but either way you need to invoke `applyCss` manually. I remember this was also discussed on the openjfx-dev mailing list, but I think the result of that discussion is summarized in the linked blog post.